# Why am I not prompted for sudo actions in the GUI when connecting via RDP?

Tags: kde, remote-desktop, xrdp, x11rdp

I have a couple machines I connect to from a Windows machine via xRDP. I'm using the x11rdp back end with xRDP. My desktop is KDE. 
When performing actions I would ordinarally get asked for my PW to perform, I don't get a prompt when I'm connecting remotely.

I was experimenting with some information I found for other distros that seem to indicate the issue is with xauthority not being set correctly on login. But I can't find the right way to set things up under KDE and make sure x11rdp is doing what needs to be done on login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I found an answer after combining 2 other answers on the subject. 
The gist of it seems to be that there was some problem with the .Xauthority file.

I pieced together something that seems to fix the issue based on 2 other bits of information I found at the following links:

https://superuser.com/questions/806637/xauth-not-creating-xauthority-file
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=61971

Here is what I did:

```
    # Rename the existing .Xauthority file by running the following command
    mv .Xauthority old.Xauthority 

    # xauth with complain unless ~/.Xauthority exists
    touch ~/.Xauthority

    # I have xRDP set up to start at display 10. 
    # I'm the only user and sessions reconnect so I only use a single entry.
    mcookie|sed -e 's/^/add :10 . /'|xauth -q
```

On a quick check after rebooting the system, I was prompted for my password when accessing the gnome disk manager which it never used to do.